# Having trouble understanding the concept of multiplicative inverse of modulo

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to solve equations like this
$$27x \equiv 10 \pmod 4$$

I understand that in a regular equation you have to multiply by the inverses of each number to isolate the variable. For example:
$$27x = 10 \Leftrightarrow x = 10/27$$

You can't do that with modulo so the method that is used is to find if the gcd = 1, if it does it can be solved and you work your way back and write 1 as a linear conbination of 27 and 4 in this case, skipping a lot of steps you get

$$1 = 7*4 + (−1)*27$$
Then you multiply both sides by 10
$$10 = 70*4 + (−10)*27$$

And this can be rewritten as 
$$10 + 70*4 = -10*27 \Leftrightarrow \\
-10*27 \equiv 10 \pmod 4$$

I don't understand why the answer is $x=2$ and not $x=-10$. -10 is 2 mod 4. Yet both -10*27 and 2*27 are 2 mod 4, not 10. I don't understand. The idea of a multiplicative inverse still puzzles me.

Comment: They are both correct. 2 is just preferable since it's less than 4 and greater than or equal to 0.

Comment: But 27*2 isn't 10 mod 4.

Comment: What you need to fully understand is the notion of congruence class ant the fact they have a representative, which for this modulus is usually chosen among $\{0,1,2,3\}$.

Comment: You'd want to check your arithmetic on that $27\cdot2\equiv10\pmod4$.

Comment: $27\cdot 2$ 1s congruent to $10\bmod 4$ since $27\equiv 3$, so $27\cdot 2\equiv 3\cdot 2=6\equiv 10\mod 4$.

Comment: $27\cdot 2 = 54 = 5\cdot 10 + 4 \equiv 10\bmod 4$. But at the same time, $10 = 2\cdot 4\equiv 10\bmod 4$, so $10\equiv 2\bmod 4$.

Comment: You could simplify $ 27x\equiv10\bmod4$ to ${3x\equiv2\bmod4}$ (can you see both $2$ and $-10$ satisfy the latter?)

Comment: Actually we *can* do modular arithmetic with fractions as long as we restrict to fractions with denominator *coprime* to the modulus, so $\,a/b \equiv ab^{-1}.\,$  Here $$\bmod 4\!:\,\ x\equiv \frac{10}{27}\equiv \frac{2}{-1}\equiv -2\equiv 2$$ You can find many [examples in my answers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20mod%20dfrac)

Comment: "I don't understand why the answer is x=2 and not x=−10".  You aren't solving for integers.  You are solving for a *class* of integers.  And the solution is the class of integers that are congruent to $2$.  Which includes both $2$ and $-10$.  If you want to can this class $2$ (because $2$ is in it) or if you want to call this $-10$ (because $-10$ is in it) or if you want to call it $6$ or $-622$ it doesn't matter.  $2 \equiv -10 \equiv 6\equiv -622\pmod 4$ so they all belong to the same equivalence class and you can refer to it be any of those solutions you want.

Comment: "But 27*2 isn't 10 mod 4".  Of course it is.  $27*2 = 54=4*11 + 10$.  So $27*2 - 10 = 44$ and $4|44$ so because $4|27*2 -10$ we know, by definition, that $27*2 \equiv 10\pmod 4$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$-10$ *is* $2\pmod4$.  So either answer will do.  $27\cdot 2\cong27\cdot-10\cong10\pmod4$.

Also, $2\cong10\pmod 4$.  So it all works out.

As you noted, $x$ has an inverse $\pmod n$ precisely when $(x,n)=1$.

So you have $-1\cdot27+7\cdot 4=1$.  Thus $27^{-1}\cong-1\pmod4$.

So we can "solve" $27x\cong10\pmod 4$ by multiplying both sides by $27^{-1}$ or $-1$ thus:  $x=-1\cdot 10\cong-10\cong2\pmod 4$.

Answer (score 4):

For the equation that you have given, $27$ does have a multiplicative inverse modulo $4$ since $$27\times3\equiv 1\pmod 4$$ so you can solve the equation in the 'normal' way:-
$$x\equiv 10\times3\equiv 2\pmod 4.$$

Comment: Yes it is:  $-27-1=-28=-7\cdot 4$.

Comment: I cannot see a problem with this. The first equation (mod 4) is just $1=28-27$ and the second is -27=1$. both are correct.

Comment: Sorry @Chris Custer - answered at the same time!

Comment: No problem.   The comment is gone.  Guess the OP figured it out.

Comment: I'm still confused. I took this from here https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse311/15au/documents/ModularEquivalences.pdf. At the bottom of page 1 the author says "First, we find the multiplicative inverse of 27 modulo 4. That is, we find a y such that 27y ≡ 1 (mod 4)." The original equation is "27y ≡ **10** (mod 4)". Are these two ys the same y?

Comment: The multiplicative inverse, in this case $-1$, or $3$, or anything else in the equivalence classes of $3\pmod4$, is used to solve the equation.   See my answer below.

Comment: They're different $y$'s, if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Since $37\ne 0\pmod 4,$ divide both sides by $37$ to get $$x=\frac{10}{37}\pmod 4=\frac{10+4n}{37}.$$ You need now only find integer values of $n$ that make $x$ an integer. Clearly, for positive $n,$ we must have $n>6.$

An easier way is to reduce both sides modulo $4$ and search for solutions in $\{0,1,2,3\}.$ Then the equation becomes $x=2,$ whence all solutions have the form $2+4n$ for integer $n.$

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember you are not solving for integers but for *classes* of integers.

There a four classes of integers.

There is $ZERO = \{.....,-12,-8,-4,0,4,8,12,.....\}$.  This is the class of all integers that are divisible by $4$.

There is $ONE = \{.....,-11,-7,-3,1,5,9,13,......\}$.  This is the class of all integer that have $1$ as a remainder when you divide by $4$.

There is $TWO = \{.....,-14,-10,-6,-2,2,6,10,14,18,22,26,30,34,38,42,46,50,54=2*27, 58,....\}$.  This is the class of all integers that have $2$ as a remainder.

And the last class if $THREE = \{.....,-9,-5,-1, 3, 7,11,.....\}$.

Every integer is one and only one of these classes.  If two integers $a,b$ are in the same class we say they are equivalent or congruent and we write $a \equiv b \pmod 4$.  This will mean four things i) $a = b + 4k$ for some multiple $4k$ of $4$; ii) that $a-b=4k$ so $a-b$ is a multiple of $4$ or in other words $4|a-b$.  iii) $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder when divided by $4$ and iv) $a$ and $b$ are both in the same one of the four classes.

And they are for all our purposes considered to be the same.

So in solving $27x \equiv 10\pmod 4$ we want to know what class $x$ belongs to given that $27x$ and $10$ are in the same class.

You figured out $1 = 4*7 + (-1)*27$.  This means $1$ and $(-1)*27$ are both in the same class; $1\equiv (-1)*27 \pmod 4$ and, indeed, both are in $ONE = \{....., -31, -27, -23, -19,-15,-11,-7,-3, 1, 4, ....\}$. So $1\equiv (-1)*27$.

You then multiplied both sides by $10$ and got $10 = 4*70 + (-10)*27$.  This the hard way to do it but it isn't wrong.  $10$ and $-270$ are both in the same class and $10\equiv -270\pmod 4$.  They are both in $TWO = \{........, -270= 4*(-68)+2, -266,-262, ........, -2,2, 6,10, 14,.....\}$.

So the $x$s that will put $10$ and $27x$ will all be in the same class that $-10$ is.  And that class is .... $TWO = \{......,-10,-6, -2,2,6,10,.....\}$.

....... that's the hard way to do it....

The easy way is:

$27x \equiv 10\pmod 4$.  Now we can replace $27$ with anything in the same class as it.   As $27 = 4*6 + 3$ we know that $27$ is in $THREE$. And $3$ is in THREE.  SO we can replace $27$ with $3$ and the whole thing will still be true.

SO $3x\equiv 10 \pmod 4$.  And we know $10 = 2*4 + 2$ so $10\in TWO$ and $2\in TWO$ so we can replace $10$ with $2$ and everything will still be true.

$3x \equiv 2\pmod 4$.

Now we know that because $\gcd (3,4) = 1$ that there is an integer, we will call it $INV(3)$. so that $INV(3)\times 3 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  What class is $INV(3)$ in?

Well, a bit of experimenting and we notice that $3\times 3=9 = 2*4 + 1\equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  So $INV(3)$ can be any number that is in the same class that $3$ is in.

So we can multiply both sides by $3$ and get:

$3*3x \equiv 2*3 \pmod 4$

$9x \equiv 6 \pmod 4$ and we can replace $9$ with $1$ and get

$x \equiv 6\pmod 4$.

So $x$ is in the same class that $6$ is in.  That is $TWO$.

That is the same clase that $2$ is in, and that $10$ is in or that $-10$ is s in or that $(-2)*27$ is.

So $x \equiv 6\pmod 4 \equiv  2\pmod 4\equiv 10\pmod 4 \equiv -10\pmod 4 \equiv -54\pmod 4$ and *any* one of those can be used to express a solution.

$2$ is the prefered solution because it is convenient to choose values between $0$ and $3$.  But all of them are equally correct.  $x$ can be any number in $TWO$.

.... and now, ... I can tell you that no-one actually calls these classes $ZERO, ONE, TWO THREE$.  We just refer to them by *any* integer that is in the clases.

So $x \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ is considered a solution.

Comment: 4 is not in ONE in the second use.